# Error in reading file name from Spring Boots Resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I develop an Asymmetric-Crypto application, using public-private key to encrypt file in java and it worked well but when I tried it in Spring boot I get java.lang.NullPointerException: null exception. Below are my code sample

```
@Component
public class Loader {

    private Cipher cipher;

    PrivateKey privateKey;

    public String enText;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Value("${classpath:asymetric.private.key-store}")
    private String file;

    public Loader() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    }

    public String encryptText(String msg, PrivateKey key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }

    public PrivateKey getPrivate(String filename) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());// the error is from here
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
    }

    public String encryptWithKey(String msg) throws Exception {
        Loader loader = new Loader();
        Resource res = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:KeyPair/privateKey");
        //privateKey = loader.getPrivate("KeyPair/privateKey");
        privateKey = loader.getPrivate(res.getFilename());
        return loader.encryptText(msg, privateKey);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void load() throws Exception {
        Loader loader = new Loader();
        String msg = "Hello , I am here";
        loader.encryptWithKey(msg);
    }
}
```

In normal java console environment, I use

```
`byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File("KeyPair/privateKey").toPath());`
```

and it worked but not in spring boot environment, all I get is the below error.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-23 10:23:45.591 ERROR 3048 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.polaris.RegistryServiceApplication.main(RegistryServiceApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.polaris.loader.Loader.encryptWithKey(Loader.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.polaris.loader.Loader.load(Loader.java:77) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:369) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Thanks in advance.. Have been on this for 2 days now..PLEASE..

Comment: Look at the stacktrace, the cause is at line 67 in Loader,encryptWithKey. Guessing the path to the key is not found and returns null but we don’t know what line 67 is.  We also don’t know if there is really a file there. Did you put the file in the class path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because you make *new File(filename).toPath();* and it isn't correct. I've tried to invoke your code and it falled there.

try to read a file so way:

```
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(res.getURI()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error clearly states that -

In the above code you have autowired ResourceLoader class and in spring if you want to autowired any property of a class then its needs to declare that class i.e. ResouceLoader to be spring bean.

@Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

So when you call encryptWithKey on ResourceLoader class you will get NPE.